# Как правильно: "9 грамм" или "9 граммов"?

Tags: лексика, орфоэпия

Как правильно: "9 грамм" или "9 граммов"?

Comment: Ну, это зависит от контекста по-моему!

Answer (score 1):

Орфографический словарь
грамм, -а, р. мн. -ов, счетн. ф. грамм и -ов

Большой толковый словарь
ГРАММ, -а; мн. род. граммов и грамм; м. [франц. gramme]
Единица массы в метрической системе мер, одна тысячная доля килограмма

http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&word=%E3%F0%E0%EC%EC

Answer (score 0):

Оба варианта верны.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.e-reading.org.ua/chapter.php/88923/25/Rozental%27_-_Govorite_i_pishite_po-russki_pravil%27no.html

Помидоров было пять килограммов (вариативность окончаний существительных в родительном падеже множественного числа)

```
  Когда я сказал соседям, что урожай в теплице я вырастил небольшой — «всего пять килограммов четыреста граммов помидоров», они заулыбались. А между тем я построил фразу правильно, по всем правилам «грамматического искусства». Так в чём же дело? По-видимому, в том, что она звучит несколько искусственно.
  Действительно, мы скорее скажем 400 грамм масла, чем 400 граммов масла, килограмм помидор, чем килограмм помидорови т.п. Здесь действует своеобразная тенденция к «экономии языковых средств»: в живой речи, как правило, употребляется более короткий вариант. В одних случаях окончание -овв форме родительного падежа множественного числа существительных мужского рода перестало использоваться не только в устной речи, но и на письме: «победил» вариант с нулевым окончанием. Так, употребляют «экономные» словосочетания: отряд солдат, группа партизан, пара сапог(а раньше говорили «отряд солдатов», «группа партизанов», «пара сапогов»). То же касается и названий некоторых национальностей (с основой на -ни -р) среди грузин, лезгин, осетин, туркмен, башкир(а раньше бы сказали: «среди грузинов, лезгинов, осетинов, туркменов, башкиров»). «Потеряли» окончание -ови названия единиц измерения: 100 ампер, 60 ватт, 220 вольти т.п.
  В других случаях окончание -овсохраняется в письменной речи: 200 граммов, килограмм помидоров, пять апельсинов, ящик мандаринов, немного баклажанов, но отпадает в речи устной: 400 грамм, тонна помидор, десять апельсин, ящик мандарин, несколько баклажан.
  Для подтверждения победы более коротких форм приведём ещё и такой факт: в первой половине XIX в. слова афиша, буря, кастрюля, пустыня, роща, сплетняи некоторые другие имели в форме родительного падежа множественного числа окончание -ей(а не нулевое окончание, как сейчас): (нет) афишей, бурей, кастрюлей, пустыней, рощей, сплетней.
   Если вы все поняли, то решите несложные задачи. 
  1. Если у вас есть несколько знакомых девочек по имени Оля, то как вы скажете: Подарки для наших...2. Заключённое в скобки слово поставьте в нужной форме: Купить несколько (простыня)3. Раскройте скобки: В углу стояло несколько (кочерга).
   Проверьте себя: 
  1. У А.П. Чехова: Оль. 2.  Просты?нь(сравните: б?ня — бань, ды?ня — дынь, я?блоня — яблонь). 3. Чтобы себя не мучить, сопоставьте: серьга — серег(с беглым е), стало быть: кочерга — кочерег.
```